# How do I debug why Imageresizer isn't working?

Tags: imageresizer, episerver

I have installed Imageresizer in an existing EPiServer project, but when uring the queries on images I only get the original image.

I have tried this on an image that is present on the site:

```
http://localhost:15000/globalassets/image.jpg?width=100
```

But I just get image.jpg in full size.

I can access http://localhost:15000/resizer.debug and there is no errors besides:

```
1 Issues detected:

(Warning):  To potentially see additional errors here, perform an image resize request.
```

I have checked everything here https://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/troubleshoot and my Web.config is as it should be.

I installed the plugin with the commands:

```
Install-Package ImageResizer.MVCWebConfig
Install-Package ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache
Install-Package ImageResizer.Plugins.PrettyGifs
```

according to this blog post: http://www.frederikvig.com/2013/01/add-powerful-image-resizing-cropping-and-manipulation-support-to-your-episerver-website/ and the official docs.

The plugin seems to be correctly installed as far as I can understand, it simply does not resize the images.

If I try to add .ashx I get a 404 page:

```
http://localhost:15000/globalassets/image.jpg.ashx?width=100
```

I don't know how I could investigate this further, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure why it did not work, but this plugin fixed it! I just installed it from NuGet and then it imageresizer worked as expected.

https://github.com/valdisiljuconoks/ImageResizer.Plugins.EPiServerBlobReader

Comment: Install-Package : Unable to find package 'ImageResizer.Plugins.EPiServerBlobReader'
Looks like it's not there any more...